# Set correct data type with mongodb and python

Tags: python, mongodb

I've just started using mongodb via the pyhton drive (pymongo). When I'm posting new data (which actually comes from a MySQL db) some data types appear incorrectly mapped. For example, some single digit number are inserted as long ints, a timestamp is inserted as a string. Also the date which is stored in MySQL as YY-MM-DD is changed to YY-MM-DD 00:00:00 (i.e a time is added).This seems like a waste of space, is this normal procedure for mongodb or should I somehow change the data types which are incorrectly(?) mapped?

ps I did search through the docs as mongodb but I couldn't find anything to match my query.

```
post = {
    "title": video_title,
    "ext_id": video_external_id,
    "source": video_source,
    "date_added": d1,
    "views":{
              "views_all": views_all,
              "views_year": views_yr,
              "views_day": views_day,
              "views_week": views_wk,
              "views_month": views_mo
              },
    "video_type": 0,
    "hd": video_hd,
    "features": featured,
    "video_thumbs": video_thumbnails,
    "video_main_thumb": video_main_thumbnail,
    "length": video_length,
    "length_sort": video_length,

    "rating": {
              "rating_all": rating_all,
              "rating_year": rating_yr,
              "rating_day": rating_day,
              "rating_week": rating_wk,
              "rating_month": rating_mo
              }
        }
posts = db.posts
post_id = video_list.insert(post)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> For example, some single digit number are inserted as long ints

PyMongo stores python 2.x long as BSON int64 regardless of value, python int as BSON int32 *or* BSON int64 depending on the value of the int. See [the table here](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/bson/son.html#bson.son.SON) for a mapping of python types to BSON types.

> a timestamp is inserted as a string

Assuming the timestamp was passed in ISO-8601 format that's correct. If you want to store the timestamp as a BSON datetime pass a python datetime object instead.

> Also the date which is stored in MySQL as YY-MM-DD is changed to YY-MM-DD 00:00:00 (i.e a time is added)

[BSON](http://bsonspec.org/spec.html) (the storage format used by MongoDB) does not have a date type without a time element. It is up to your application to convert dates to datetimes.